# Differential equation system, Jacobian matrix, characteristic equation

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis

We assume the differential equation system: $X'=σ(Y-X),Y'=X(ρ-Z)-Y,Z'=XY-βZ$. I can calculate the equilibrium points as:

```
Solve[σ (Y - X) == 0 && 3 X (ρ - Z) - Y == 0 && X Y - β Z == 0, {X, Y,Z}]


a_ 1 = {{X -> 0, Y -> 0, 
Z -> 0}, {X -> -((Sqrt[β] Sqrt[-1 + 3 ρ])/Sqrt[3]), 
Y -> -((Sqrt[β] Sqrt[-1 + 3 ρ])/Sqrt[3]), 
Z -> 1/3 (-1 + 3 ρ)}, {X -> (Sqrt[β] Sqrt[-1 + 3 ρ])/Sqrt[3], 
Y -> (Sqrt[β] Sqrt[-1 + 3 ρ])/Sqrt[3], Z -> 1/3 (-1 + 3 ρ)}}[[2]]

a_ 2 = Last[{{X -> 0, Y -> 0, 
Z -> 0}, {X -> -((Sqrt[β] Sqrt[-1 + 3 ρ])/Sqrt[3]), 
Y -> -((Sqrt[β] Sqrt[-1 + 3 ρ])/Sqrt[3]), 
Z -> 1/3 (-1 + 3 ρ)}, {X -> (Sqrt[β] Sqrt[-1 + 3 ρ])/Sqrt[3], 
Y -> (Sqrt[β] Sqrt[-1 + 3 ρ])/Sqrt[3], Z -> 1/3 (-1 + 3 ρ)}}]

a_ 3 = First[{{X -> 0, Y -> 0, 
Z -> 0}, {X -> -((Sqrt[β] Sqrt[-1 + 3 ρ])/Sqrt[3]), 
Y -> -((Sqrt[β] Sqrt[-1 + 3 ρ])/Sqrt[3]), 
Z -> 1/3 (-1 + 3 ρ)}, {X -> (Sqrt[β] Sqrt[-1 + 3 ρ])/Sqrt[3], 
Y -> (Sqrt[β] Sqrt[-1 + 3 ρ])/Sqrt[3], Z -> 1/3 (-1 + 3 ρ)}}]
```

I have to calculate the Jacobian matrix for each of the three equilibrium point and then their characteristic polyonymial. My approach is to calculate separate a matrix with the components of the Jacobian matrix and the put $a_1, a_2, a_3$. Is there a different method?

Comment: One quick thing, you can't define variables as `a_ 1`, etc.  Easier to save the results of `Solve` with `eq = Solve[...` then take parts of eq.

Comment: I am a beginner, so it would be helpful (for me) to be more analytic

Answer (score 5):

Once we have the equilibrium points as

```
equs = {sigma (X - Y), X (rho - Z) - Y, X Y - beta Z}
sols = Solve[equs == 0, {X, Y, Z}]
```

you can calculate the associated jacobian to each equilibrium point as

```
Js = Grad[equs, {X, Y, Z}] /. sols
```

and the corresponding characteristic polynomials as

```
Table[CharacteristicPolynomial[Js[[k]], lambda], {k, 1, Length[Js]}]
```

or if you know the value of the parameters involved

```
parms = {sigma -> 10, rho -> 28, beta -> 8/3};
eigen = Table[Eigenvalues[Js[[k]] /. parms], {k, 1, Length[Js]}] // N;
eigen  // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Huh, didn't know you could just use `0` in `Solve` like that!

Comment: nice, may I ask something? for specific values: $β=\frac{8}{3}, σ=10, ρ=28$ can we calculate $λ$ and then use Eigenvalue command?

Comment: The eigenvalues calculation was included.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253201/linearization-of-the-ode-system-problems

Answer (score 3):

Let's start by making a list of the equations:

```
eqns = {σ (Y - X), 3 X (ρ - Z) - Y, X Y - β Z};
```

Then solve for the equilibria and save the result in `eq`:

```
eq = Solve[eqns == {0, 0, 0}, {X, Y, Z}]
```

Make the generic Jacobian:

```
j = D[eqns, {{X, Y, Z}}]
```

and then you can evaluate it at particular equilibria using `/.`:

```
j /. eq[[1]]
j /. eq[[2]]
j /. eq[[3]]
```

Once you have those, it's easy to find the characteristic polynomial or eigenvalues:

```
CharacteristicPolynomial[j /. eq[[1]], λ]
Eigenvalues[j /. eq[[1]]

(*
(-β - λ) (λ + λ^2 + σ + λ σ - 3ρ σ)
{-β, 1/2 (-1 - σ - Sqrt[1 - 2σ + 12ρ σ + σ^2]), 
 1/2 (-1 - σ + Sqrt[1 - 2σ + 12ρ σ + σ^2])}
*)
```

Answer (score 3):

The vector field defined by your system:

```
f1 = σ (Y - X);
f2 = 3 X (ρ - Z) - Y;
f3 = X Y - β Z;
 F = {f1, f2, f3};
 V = {X, Y, Z};
```

The equilibria:

```
P1 = Solve[F == 0, V][[1]]
P2 = Solve[F == 0, V][[2]]
P3 = Solve[F == 0, V][[3]]
```

The Jacobian matrix:

```
J = FullSimplify[D[F, {V}]]
    MatrixForm[J]
```

The three linear approximations:

```
J1 = FullSimplify[J /. P1];
      MatrixForm[J1]
J2 = FullSimplify[J /. P2];
      MatrixForm[J2]
J3 = FullSimplify[J /. P3];
      MatrixForm[J3]
```

The three characteristic polynomials:

```
pol1 = -Collect[CharacteristicPolynomial[J1, λ], λ, Simplify]
pol2 = -Collect[CharacteristicPolynomial[J2, λ], λ, Simplify]
pol3 = -Collect[CharacteristicPolynomial[J3, λ], λ, Simplify]
```

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/253201/linearization-of-the-ode-system-problems